# Runtime error while merging arrays

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am currently trying to merge arrays and I have completed most of the program but I keep getting a error. I tried changing it up and I kept digging myself into a hole and getting farther from getting it right, so I went back to my original code.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;

class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");


    int[] array1 = new int[10000];
    int[] array2 = new int[10000];
    int input = 0; //input for arrays
    int count = 0; //count for element position

    //adds input into first array
    while (input >= 0) {
      input = scan.nextInt();
      array1[count] = input;
      count++;
    }
    count = 0;

    //adds input into second array
    System.out.println ("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
    input = 0;
    while (input >= 0) {
      input = scan.nextInt();
      array2[count] = input;
      count++;
    }
    //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array1));
    //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array2));

    //finds length of the input arrays
    int num1 = 0;
    while (array1[num1] >= 0 ){
      num1++;
    }
    int num2 = 0;
    while (array2[num2] >= 0) {
      num2++;
    }

    //checks if arrays are input in order
    for (int i = 0; i < num1 - 1; i++) {
      if (array1[i] > array1[i + 1])
        count = -15;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num2 - 1; i++) {
      if (array2[i] > array2[i + 1])
        count = -15;
    }

    //outputs first array
    System.out.println("First Array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
      System.out.print(array1[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    //outputs second array
    System.out.println("Second Array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
      System.out.print(array2[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    //outputs if array if no errors
    if (count == -15){
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println ("ERROR: Array not in correct order");
    }
    else {
      String answer = "";

      //checks for biggest number
      int biggest = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        if (array1[i] > biggest)
          biggest = array1[i];
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
        if (array2[i] > biggest)
          biggest = array2[i];
      }
      System.out.println ();


      //merges the arrays
      for (int i = 0; i <= biggest; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < num1; x++) {
          if (array1[x] == i)
            answer += i + " ";
      }
        for (int x = 0; x < num2; x++) {
          if (array2[x] == i)
            answer += i + " ";
      }
      }

      System.out.println ("Merged Array: "); 
      System.out.println (answer);
    }

  }
}
```

now here is the error message.

```
<b>Runtime Error</b>

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Main.main(Main.java:243)
at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:94)
at Ideone.test(Main.java:42)
at Ideone.main(Main.java:29)
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Try to post only the relevant piece of code; currently it is too long and keeps people away from understanding it.

Comment: From the call stack the exception originates on line 29. Start from there your investigation

Comment: where is the method test and assertRegex? it's actually on assertRegex 94th line from main